# Publising Failed - We are unable to create an authentication session

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to upload an iOS App to the App Store in Visual Studio on my Mac.

However, I am getting this error shown in the image.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 58):

1. Please go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and in the "Security" section generate an app-specific password.
2. When you begin to publish your app to the App Store use this password with your Apple ID in Visual Studio (see an attached screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thx for this answer, it was really perfect to find this after a frustrating evening where i wasnt able to publish. It actually says App Specific Password, and i didnt read it correctly.